# Implicit conversion to Func

Tags: c#, delegates, lambda, anonymous-methods, implicit

Let's say I have an interface `IMyInterface<T>` that simply describes one function:

```
public interface IMyInterface<T>
{
    T MyFunction(T item);
}
```

I could just about replace this with `Func<T, T>`, but I want the interface for semantic reasons.  Can I define an implicit conversion between that interface and `Func<T,T>` such that I could pass an anonymous delegate or lambda as an argument to a function that accepts this interface as a parameter, just like if I had used `Func<T,T>` instead?

To demonstrate, using the interface declared above I want a function like this:

```
public T TestFunction<T>(IMyInterface myInterface, T value)
{
    return myInterface.MyFunction(value);
}
```

That I can call like this:

```
TestFunction(x => x + " world", "hello");
```

And the result would be "hello world".

Comment: Did you mean to call IMyInterface.MyFunction() in the second code block?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since interfaces in C# cannot contain definitions for operators (or any static methods for that matter), I believe the answer is *no*. The alternative is to use a class (can't be abstract unfortunately, since static members/operators fair no better here than in interfaces). This would allow you to define the `implicit` conversion operator and therefore be able to use the type precisely how you've specified.

In the class (which you could perhaps make `virtual` if required), you would define it something like the following.

```
public class MyClass<T>
{
    public static implicit operator MyClass<T>(Func<T, T> func)
    {
        return new MyClass<T>() { MyFunction = func };
    }

    public MyClass()
    {
    }

    public Func<T, T> MyFunction
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
```

Your definition of `TestFunction` in your question should then work exactly as you coded it.

```
public T TestFunction<T>(IMyInterface myInterface, T value)
{
    return myInterface.MyFunction(value);
}
```

And likewise the call to `TestFunction`:

```
TestFunction<string>(x => return x + " world", "hello");
```

This may not be precisely what you're looking for, but it's nonetheless reasonably close, and moreover very likely the best you'll be able to get.

Comment: How does TestFunction convert a lambda into IMyInterface? You define a class MyClass, not an interface. Some more editing required, I think...

Comment: @Earwicker: Take a closer look - the implicit conversion operator should do that for you, unless I'm mistaken. Also, if you read the start of my post I mention that it's not possible with an interface, and only a (non-abstract) class.

Comment: This is pretty much what I expected, but I've been known to overlook things before and hoped that would be the case this time.  Sadly, it's not.  In fact I already had my own concrete implementation that is eerily similar to what you posted.

Comment: Yeah, anything "better" would require support for static interfaces, and unfortunately that doesn't exist (maybe something for a future version of C#?). At least it's a positive sign in terms of design that we've come to very similar implementations. :)

Comment: I know it has been a while, but what is the definition of `IMyInterface` in your definition of `TestFunction`? Your code doesn't work because only standard implicit conversions can occur before a user-defined conversion, and the conversion from lambda (or anonymous method) to delegate is not one of them (see specification 6.3.1). (Also, return is illegal in a lambda without braces.)

Comment: why do you say you can't do it with an abstract class? if you couldn't before, you can now.